# Proper Name Transliteration API

Tags: api, transliteration

I'm looking for a transliteration API.

I checked [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) and [Microsoft Translator API](http://www.microsoft.com/translator/translator-api.aspx), but neither can handle name transliteration to English (phonetic spelling of the name in English).

The only relevant API I found so far was [Google **Transliteration** API](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/), however, it's deprecated.

Any help would be appreciated

### Samples:

- 崔帅 --> Cui Shuai
- 李军 --> Li Jun
- לב כבד --> Lev Kaved

The idea is that a names with meanings like "Apple" will be spelled out in English, not translated by meaning.

Related article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization